# Will an IP camera still work if the wifi router breaks or is turned off?

Tags: wifi, security-theater

Im using and IP Camera at home and I have the footage being sent to an online file storage service as well as my handheld device through the internet. If the wifi router at home is turned off or somehow malfunctions and is no longer working, will I still be able to view the footage from my handheld device or online on the storage service?

Comment: What is confusing in your question that you are trying to get an answer for? If the router that connects you to internet is down, you have no way of sending the footage from your camera to your online storage server which means that you will not abe able to see the live footage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a WiFi camera. If it's wired and the same wireless router is how it connects to the internet.

In a simple word, No. No transport, no storage.

Put the router on an UPS.

And if it's a WiFi camera, it can be jammed.

Answer (score 0):

No, You will not. The footage transmission just stops when it can no longer access the internet.(imagine an ink-less pen, you can write with it, but no use of writing since it is not stored / not visible) Make sure to let your router connect to an alternative power source (with any of your favorite options) when the actual one fails.